# How do I store and then retrieve a link to an image in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to be able to show a user a picture from one form page to the next. The picture will be dynamic based on what he or she is doing. So, I need to store the path link to that image in a cookie and then load that image on the next page.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

and then do:

```
$.cookie("img", img_url);
```

[OR]

You can set and get cookie using these functions: (From [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html))

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I got the cookie to store the entire image link in a cookie, on the next page it displays the image link in full. How do I get it to show the image instead of the image link?

Comment: Did you wrap the url around the img source attribute?

Comment: The image is found through a change function that looks up the particular images url based on what they've selected. So, I can't do the wrap img source from the starting page. Can I wrap the image source in the 2nd page and put the cookie inside the image source?

Answer (score 0):

Use document.cookie to set and get the image URLs.

check this cite for details: [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

It shows that you didn't do much research on this simple thing.

Comment: Actually, I did. I already saw the link you gave me and it didn't help with this issue. Fortunately, someone else gave me an extremely helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple JSFiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qm7WU/)

```
// Assign the cookie
document.cookie = "imgpath=/your/image.png";
alert(document.cookie);

// Use a regular expression to get the path from the entire cookie string. Sanitizations are left up to you.
var imgPath = /imgpath=([^;]+)/i.exec(document.cookie)[1];
alert(imgPath);
```

I suggest using the jQuery.cookie plugin mentioned in the other answers though, no need to make it any harder than it already is.

Here is the regular expression explained: http://regex101.com/r/qH6rB5/1 - it shows how the actual value you are interested in, is captured.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, both yours and vasa have helped me with what I need.

Comment: I got the cookie to store the entire image link in a cookie, on the next page it displays the image link in full. How do I get it to show the image instead of the image link?

Comment: You'd have to add an `<img>` element and set it's source to the cookie's value. This is out of the scope for this question though. :)